# django, secondary data in subfolders

Tags: django

I am working on an informational site.  I am attempting to access files in a subdirectory using data from the django db.

Ex: if the record.id = 1 and the file is desc.txt, I want to grab /1/desc.txt

I currently have two items that I'm trying to access this way.  The image file will work if I hard code the location, but I haven't been able to get it to work from the record data.  The other one, I'm trying to load a description file into a div using jQuery and .html(), and can't get it to work at all.

The relevant section of code:
{% if aRecord %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}

```
<h1>{{ aRecord.Name }}</h1>
<br/>
Born: {{aRecord.Birth}}<br/>
Died: {{aRecord.Death}}<br/>
<div id="descArea"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
<script>
    descfile = 'Authors/1/desc.txt';
    $('#descArea').text(descfile);
    $.get("{% static 'Authors/1/desc.txt' %}", function(data) {
        $('#descArea').html(data);
    });
</script>
<br/>
```

{% else %}

Requested author not found.

{% endif %}

This is the hard-coded version that works, but I need it to work from the aRecord data.  The 1 in both cases should come from the record id, and the image filename in the img tag should as well.

Comment: Is it possible to share the file to understand where it might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is really a question about how to produce a file path from dynamic data. Is that the case? If so, you will probably need to use string substitution.

In order to produce a string like `'/1/desc.txt'` where the `1` is given by a record id, you could do something like this:
`path = '/{}/desc.txt'.format(record.id)`.